# Load .ply in SceneView

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, metalkit

I have a .ply file with some mesh information.
I want to display the contents of this file as a scene in SceneView.

```
if let url : URL? = self.dir!.appendingPathComponent("color_model.ply") {
        let asset = MDLAsset(url: url!)
        let scene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: asset)
        let colorModelNode = SCNNode()
        colorModelNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        colorModelNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
                node.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(colorModelNode)
```

I tried loading it as an MDLAsset but I get a Bad Access exception.
How can I load a .ply to sceneKit?